# inconsistent DB record returns - migrated accessDB to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my DB that has 2 bit fields, one called **Active** and one called **Public**..For all records Active and Public are both set to 1/true

When my query is

```
Select Top 1000 * from [NewsStory] WHERE Active = 1
```

I get all my records

When I change **Active to Public** it returns nothing...even though I can see all the Public fields displaying true the exact same as the Actives beside them.

```
Select Top 1000 * from [NewsStory] WHERE Public = 1
```

Is there something wrong with my DB conversion import? I don't understand at all why Active = 1 works but Public = 1 fails..

Thanks for any help

Comment: this might be linked to another problem I am experiencing where if I display a CreatedDate record ahead of the Story record, the Story record returns nothing..

Comment: `Public` is a reserved word.  Try `[Public]`.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that fixed this problem!!

Comment: @JimHewitt are you going to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Public` is a SQL Server reserved word. When you use a column name that is a reserved word you must embed it in brackets. For example, you should be using `[Public]` in your `Select` clause.